# web notification with input action

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

i'm using firebase messaging to push notification to web client.

when notification is pushed i show it with action buttons and i am able to andle the click

what i want to do is when user will click button, to have a small input area that the user can type in somthing and to handle that in my code

(just like 'quick reply' on whatsapp or like window.prompt() in browser)

here is my service-worker code

```
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
    notificationTitle = payload.data.title
    notificationOptions = {
        body: payload.data.body,
        actions: [{action:'ok', title: 'Ok'},{action:'dismiss', title: 'Not now'}]
    };
    return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
    switch (event.action) {
        case 'ok':
            clients.openWindow('http://localhost:5000');
            break;
        case 'dismiss':
            console.log('dismissed')
            break;
    }
}
    , false);
```

is it posible at all?

thanks

Comment: I would too like to know if there is a browser API to show an input field within the notification e.g for quickly replying to someone. I don't think there is at the moment as I couldn't find anything in the spec https://notifications.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-notification-actions

Comment: Looks to be work in progress for both, the specification and most browser vendors. See https://github.com/whatwg/notifications/issues/68

Answer (score 1):

You can add input in noti with type = 'text' and also there is placeholder attribute

Example

```
export const NotiAction = {
   reply: {
      action: "reply",
      title: "Reply",
      type: "text",
      placeholder: "Reply Comment",
   }
};
```